# What is the best way to eliminate many if-else conditions?

Tags: java, if-statement, design-patterns

We are persisting an object in the database, But before there are few conditions that need to be checked I am using if-else to perform these what is the best way to eliminate if-else statements. We are also setting response object which a map in each and every statement.

Also, in future we have to check for other conditions before creating or updating.

```
Callable<Response> callableObj = () -> {
    if(isNew){
    if(checkCreatePermission()){
       if(checkDuplicate()) {
          return foundObejct();
       } else {
           persistNewObject();
       }
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
} else {
    if(checkUpdatePermission()){
        udapteObject();
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }

}
};
```

Comment: What version of Java do you use?

Comment: i use java 8...

Comment: Are you sure you should call checkCreatePermission when isNew is false ? If the same method is called twice, then you can move that part.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. it is actually checkUpdatePermission(). Edited the question

Comment: The code misses some returns, it won't compile like that

Comment: `checkCreatePermission()` and `checkUpdatePermission()` clearly represent some security related checks which could be externalized using AOP, similar to like Spring does that using Spring Security and certain annotations like `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostFilter` and the like. It is also questionable whether to check if the object already exists in a DB i.e. as the DB will tell you with a kind of exception anyway. This avoids a previous lookup query. In short you are doing stuff that should already taken care of by the service layer below

Comment: @displayName Commenting on down- or close votes often leads to retaliation. It is therefore discouraged. See [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1288408)

Answer (score 1):

You could use some early returns/throws. Makes the code a little more readable.

```
if(isNew){
    if(!checkCreatePermission()){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    if (checkDuplicate()) {
       return foundObejct();
    }
    persistNewObject();
} else {
    if(!checkUpdatePermission()){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    udapteObject();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Best way to eliminate many if-else conditions...

One way to better code is to invert the if conditions and then factor the conditional code out into their separate methods.

The code below is functionally equivalent to the code you have written.

```
public ... originalMethod() {
    if(isNew) handleNewObject();
    else handleExistingObject();
}

private ... handleExistingObject() {
    if (!checkUpdatePermission()) throw new Exception();
    updateObject();
}

private ... handleNewObject() {
    if (!checkCreatePermission()) throw new Exception();
    if (checkDuplicate()) return foundObject();
    persistNewObject();
    //... other steps.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I like this approach it's cleaner. But the thing is I am using Callable and the code is inside callable. If I create private method outside callable will it work? Would we be having concurrency issues?

Comment: @user95814: It would depend on the method implementation. Concurrency issues can occur if the private methods are modifying class variables. If the method is working only with local data, concurrency issues would not occur. In all other cases, the actual implementation would need to be looked at.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split it down in few methods. Not sure if I got what do you need, but it could be something like

```java
    createOrUpdate() {
        if(isNew()){
            create();
        } else {
            update();
        }
    }

    create() {
        if(checkCreatePermission()){
            if(checkDuplicate()) {
                return foundObejct();
            } else {
                persistNewObject();
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    update() {
        if(checkCreatePermission()){
            udapteObject();
        } else {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get inspired from the [CoR design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). In the code below I assume that to run a `Callable` you call its `apply()` method:

```
Callable<Response> cError = () -> { throw new Exception(); };

Callable<Response> cUpdateObject = () ->
    !isNew && checkUpdatePermission() ? updateObject() : cError.apply();

Callable<Response> cPersistNewObject = () ->
    isNew && checkCreatePermission() && !checkDuplicate() ? persistNewObject() : cUpdateObject.apply();

Callable<Response> callableObj = () ->
    isNew && checkCreatePermission() && checkDuplicate() ? foundObject() : cPersistNewObject.apply();
```

With this approach, it's easy to see the conditions leading to each of the responses.

P/S: You can cache the calls to `checkCreatePermission()`, `checkUpdatePermission()`, and `checkDuplicate()` if necessary.